# sort int array, got killed by SIGABOT in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

```
void sort_int_tab(int *tab, unsigned int size);
```

I'm trying to write a function that must sort (in-place) the 'tab' int array, that contains exactly 'size'
members, in ascending order.Doubles are preserved. When I run the code i get `SIGABOT`, How can I fix this?

```
void    sort_int_tab(int *tab, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int    i;
    unsigned int    j;
    int             tmp;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < size)
        {
            if (tab[j] > tab[j + 1])
            {
                tmp = tab[j];
                tab[j] = tab[j + 1];
                tab[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (j < size)` then `if (tab[j] > tab[j + 1])`. Access to `tab[j+1]` is out of bounds for the last value of `j`.

Comment: You ran off the end of your array. And use `for` loops. `for(i=0;i<size;i++)`.

Comment: and you just increases `i` and never do anything with it? how is that supposed to sort?

Comment: @jxh I'm not allowed to use any other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the array one past its length by accessing `tab[j + 1]` when you merely made sure that `j < size`. It is possible that `j == size` and thus `j` out of bounds. To fix this issue, compare `j + 1` against the limit:

```
while (j + 1 < size) ...
```